# PHP Sort Multidimensional Array By Number Of Entries - If Equal Alphabetical

Tags: php, html, ldap

I have a multidimensional array, and I am trying to sort it so that the array with the most entries comes first, etc... Then if two arrays have the same number of entries, they should be arranged alphabetically. Also, if the entries could be sorted by the key, 'name', I think that would be great. As you can see below, I am using *ldap_sort* to sort by 'name'. But I'm sure calling too many sort functions is bad practice.

```
if ($conn == True ) {
    Try {

        // Authenticate
        $bind = ldap_bind($conn, $user, $pass);

        // Search AD
        $search = ldap_search($conn, $dn, $filter, $attr);

        // Sort
        ldap_sort($conn, $search, 'name');

        // Retrieve Data
        $records = ldap_get_entries($conn, $search);

        Foreach ($records as $record) {

            if(is_array($record) && array_key_exists('l', $record)) {

                $locations[$record['l'][0]][] = $record;

            }

            continue;

        }

    } finally {

        // Close Connection
        ldap_close($conn);

    }

} else {

    trigger_error('Unable_To_Connect_To_Server');

}

// Sort Location By Number Of Entries
array_multisort(array_map('count', $locations), SORT_DESC, $locations);
```

I guess to put it layman's terms.. Sorting entries alphabetically by their 'name' value, should be inherent. Then the arrays should be sorted by the number of entries, and if any arrays have the same number of entries they should be sorted alphabetically.

P.S. - I'm asking for help because it's hard for me to understand multidimensional arrays (especially those returned by *ldap_search*) and sorting them is even more mind-boggling to me.

**EDIT** Like I said, arrays confuse me but hopefully the below accurately depicts my intentions:

```
Array ( 
    [Location1] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [l] => Array ( 
                [count] => 1 
                [0] => Location1
            ) 
            [0] => l 
            [telephonenumber] => Array ( 
                [count] => 1 
                [0] => XXX.XXX.XXXX
            ) 
            [1] => telephonenumber 
            [department] => Array ( 
                [count] => 1 
                [0] => Department1
            ) 
            [2] => department 
            [name] => Array ( 
                [count] => 1 [0] => User1
            ) 
            [3] => name 
            [ipphone] => Array ( 
                [count] => 1 
                [0] => IPPhone1
            ) 
            [4] => ipphone 
            [mail] => Array ( 
                [count] => 1 
                [0] => user@domain.com
            ) 
            [5] => mail 
            [count] => 6 
            [dn] => DistinguishedName1
        )
    )
)
```

I cut the above short (there are hundreds of records returned) and I'm not sure I ended it correctly. But I am essentially parsing the information to output something like below.

```
c_Location1
   a_user1
   b_user1
   c_user1
a_Location2
   a_user2
   b_user2
b_location3
   a_user3
   b_user3
```

Comment: What do you mean by ordering two arrays alphabetically? Can you show sample input and the desired output?

Comment: The array returned ldap_search is what I believe is a multidimensional associative array. It has array inside array, and values can be identified by number or string.

Comment: Please post the output of `var_export($search);` so we can see what this array looks like and test our answers with it.

Comment: You're still not clear about what you mean by ordering two arrays alphabetically. If the arrays are `["c", "a", "b"]` and `["b", "d", "e"]`, which one goes first? The first one because its lowest element is `"a"`, or the second one because `"b"` is lower than `"c"`?[

Comment: You should be able to do what you want with `usort()`. You write a comparison function that returns the appropriate ordering given two input arrays, and it will sort the multi-dimensional array containing them.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to respond while I edited the original post to better reflect my intentions.

Comment: Sp if they have the same length, you want to order by `$element['name'][0]` alphabetically?

Comment: Bingo! (yes) I wasn't sure I was going to be able to relay that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that compares the lengths of the arrays. If they're the same, it compares the `name` entries. Use that as the callback function for `usort`.

```
usort($records, function($x, $y) {
    if (count($x) == count($y)) {
        $u1 = $x['name'][0];
        $u2 = $y['name'][0];
        return $u1 < $u2 ? -1 :
            ($u1 > $u2 ? 1 : 0);
    } else {
        return count($y) - count($x);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wait.. I think I misunderstood you. I'm trying to sort Locations by the number of entries they have, if they have the same amount of entries then they should be sorted alphabetically by Location. The entries themselves should (for each Location) should always be sorted alphabetically by 'name'.